# WPF Treeview ShowRootlines

Tags: wpf, treeview

Is there a way to show Root lines in a WPF Treeview?

Or do you have to resort to doing something complicated like using Control Templates

The Winforms treeview has a ShowRootLines property but none exists for the WPF treeview.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you must create your own templates to do this. [Here's a post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/30cb182c-9419-40bd-946e-87971515fb95/) in the MSDN forums with an answer from a MSFT rep on how you can accomplish this.